# understanding unexpected behavior of nchar on lists

Tags: r, list, nchar

I was playing around with code, comparing R and python behaviors, and I came across something I cannot explain in R:

```
nchar(c('zzz','xs','acgt'))
#[1] 3 2 4 

mylist<- list(a = c('zzz','xs','acgt'), b = c('aa', 'bb'))
mylist 

# $a
# [1] "zzz"  "xs"   "acgt"
# $b
# [1] "aa" "bb"
#
nchar(mylist) 
# a  b 
# 22 13 
## ?????
```

Can you please help me understand where the result comes from?

Comment: `nchar()` expects a character vector. It counts the characters of the contents of `mylist` items. The first item has 22 characters `[1] "zzz" "xs" "acgt"`

Comment: Good answers below. Adding that you might want to try `lapply(mylist, nchar)` to get the a list of nchars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nchar()` implicitly coerces its arguments to type `character`. Now let’s check what this looks like if done explicitly:

```r
mychar = as.character(mylist)
# [1] "c(\"zzz\", \"xs\", \"acgt\")" "c(\"aa\", \"bb\")"

cat(mychar, sep = "\n")
# c("zzz", "xs", "acgt")
# c("aa", "bb")

nchar(mychar)
# [1] 22 13
```

Answer (score 2):

`nchar()` first turns the list into characters, then counts them.  The behaviour may not be what you would expect, but you can see how it works if you turn your list into a character vector first.

```r
mylist<- list(a = c('zzz','xs','acgt'), b = c('aa', 'bb'))
as.character(mylist)
#> [1] "c(\"zzz\", \"xs\", \"acgt\")" "c(\"aa\", \"bb\")"
nchar(mylist)
#>  a  b 
#> 22 13
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>